# Finding position of characters in a string

Tags: python

I have created some code to determine the position of characters in a string. However, the count starts from 0 not 1.

```
string="pandas"
for i,c in enumerate(string):
    if "a"==c: print i
```

I would also be interested in a more naive solution to my problem which didn't use enumerate.

Comment: That seems like the best way.

Comment: If you want to count from `1` print `i+1`

Comment: You could use `enumerate(string, 1)` to start from 1

Comment: `pos1 = "pandas".index("a")` `pos2 = "pandas".index("a", pos1+1)` `print(pos1, pos2)`. You could use it in loop to find all `a` in longer text.

Comment: As @furas stated if you want to get all the indexes you can make a list comprehension `[idx + 1 for idx in range(len(string)) if "a" == string[idx]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start enumerate at `1` as follows:

```
for i, c in enumerate(string, 1):
    if "a"==c: print i
```

It seems you are using Python 2, so in case you want to use Python 3, use:

```
for i, c in enumerate(string, 1):
    if "a"==c: print(i)
```

A more naive solution:

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    if "a" == string[i]:
        print(i + 1)
```

Comment: The order should be `enumerate(string, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

you could also use regex:

```
import re

[m.start() for m in re.finditer('a', string)]
```

or

```
[m.start()+1 for m in re.finditer('a', string)]
```

depending on what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
string="pandas"
for i,c in enumerate(string,1):
    if "a"==c: print(i)
```

or a more python solution using `list comprehension` and `regex`:

```
[x.end() for x in re.finditer('a', string)]
```